# heroku - django images wont work in heroku but works fine locally

Tags: django, heroku, django-cms

I am new to Django and Heroku. My installation works fine locally but when its pushed to Heroku im not able to see css, js or images in my site.

This is my url patterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'blog.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
    url(r'^blog/', include('zinnia.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^' + settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip('/'), include('appmedia.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

And this is my settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static")

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Cheers
S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To serve staticfiles on Heroku, you will need to use an additional app like whitenoise. I followed these steps and was able to serve images on Heroku.

This link is the main guide:
https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Guides/blob/master/all/Heroku_Django_Deployment_Guide.md

These would be references (I would recommend going through the references also):

1) http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

2) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

3) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static

I ran into the same problem you ran into. Following the steps in the guide and references worked well for me.

Comment: why did they make an incomplete service so we need to use external use, this doesn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `DEBUG` setting set to `True` for Heroku?  If not, the `appmedia.urls` aren't going to be included.

On a related note, `django-appmedia` isn't the best way of handling static assets in Django -- as of Django 1.3, there's a contrib app called `staticfiles` (see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/), and Heroku expects that you'll be using that app.

Furthermore, `django-appmedia` appears to want the assets in a `/media/` directory in each app, whereas `staticfiles` expects assets to be in each app's `/static/` folder.

Have you looked at the Heroku documentation on Django and static assets at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets?

Comment: Hi Jason. I am already using staticfiles app and i do collectstatic locally. Again, this works fine locally but not on Heroku.

Comment: Also i checked the images url and its being served from static folder. eg: "/static/cms/images/pony.jpg"

Comment: Another interesting find. Even locally, the images and css are being served only with the django built-in server and NIT with gunicorn or foreman start....

Comment: There is nothing in your urls.py file (the one posted in your original comment) that's telling gunicorn how to find the static assets.  For example, in a staging app I have on Heroku now, I have the following lines in my project-level urls.py (apparently Stack Overflow comments don't allow carriage returns):  from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns  and then  urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns().  That's so the staging app can serve static files via gunicorn.  (The production app pushes assets to S3.)

Comment: Hi Jason. I added this and it works find now - urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
) Thanks a lot...